# View with empty filter result visible only to admin user

Tags: views

So I am new to Drupal 7, just so you know.

Here is my problem:

I created a view displaying all registered users ("members"). Following a tutorial, I managed to display their user pic, name, date joined and amount of posts. The latter was done using aggregation and the relationship filter "User: content authored".

All works great in the preview and real view, but only for the Admin role. When I log out and try it as a fake member I created for testing, the members with 0 posts don't show up.

I have searched for an answer for hours now and have fiddled with filter settings until I am blue, but no luck.

ETA: I have found that some people have had luck using the Views Field View Module. I tried it, setting up a new view for the post counter and then adding it to the parent view, but now I am getting the same post count for all users. Don't know what I am doing wrong...

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end I followed some advice I found on another somewhat similar problem which said one can go onto the Advanced Settings on your view > Query Settings > check "Disable Query Rewriting"

This worked, but anyone following this advice should be aware of the security implications regarding visibility.

Answer (score 0):

you have to look into the permissions i gueass ... you haven't set permissions to see other users profile for anonymous & authenticated users users...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have checked the user permissions and all authenticated users and members can view user profiles. The problem is that members can see members in the view but only those who have actually posted something so that their number of posts is not 0 (zero)